# Is it possible to play Kirby: Nightmare in Dreamland (Gba remake) multiplayer with a Nintendo DS?

Tags: nintendo-ds, kirby-nightmare-in-dreamland

I wonder if it is possible to play Kirby: Nightmare in Dreamland with friends, but I only have a DS with the GBA cartridge. I would love to play multi-player, if there is even a way to. Any info?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much ^^